# rm -rf does not work: 'Device or resource busy'

Tags: rm, container, openvz

I'm using OpenVZ to create containers and it creates a folder for each container to store its files. I stopped the creation of a container before it gets completed, so it created a folder for that container, but when I try to remove that folder using `rm -rf`, I get the `'Device or resource busy'` error,  but when I do `'lsof <container folder>'` or `'fuser <container folder>'`, it returns nothing, even when I do `umount <container folder>` nothing happens. So I'm not sure which process or device is using it. How can I remove this folder?

Comment: Add `sudo` and see if it removes it!

Comment: Please replace `TheFilename` with the folder name (keep the surrounding quotes) in `env DIR="TheFilename" fgrep "$( df --output=source "$DIR" | tail -1 )" /etc/mtab`, run that in a terminal, and edit your question to include the output.

Answer (score 1):

I did several umount commands and it worked well for me. For some reason, the folder has been mounted several times by openvz, so I had to umount it several times to be able to remove it.

Comment: where do you mean to put the comment?

Comment: Sorry, my fault. You can also mark this post as answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ umount /directory/

=> umount(/directory/): Resource busy -- try 'diskutil unmount'
```

So I tried with

```
diskutil unmount /directory/
```

and it works for me.